# Django authenticate unit test

Tags: django, unit-testing, authentication, mocking

I am trying to mock the return value of the django.contrib.auth authenticate method which is called within the login method of a view.

There's the view.py code:

```
def login(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
            username = get_username(request.POST.get('email')) 
            password = request.POST.get('password') 

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password) 

            if user: 
                    if user.is_active: 
                            if not request.POST.get('remember_me', None): 
                                    request.session.set_expiry(0) 
                            auth_login(request, user) 
                            return redirect('/') 
                    else: 
                            return redirect('/') # some error page 
            else: 
                    return redirect('/') # error again 
    else: 
            return render(request, 'auth/login.html')
```

And the test.py code:

```
from django.contrib import auth
...
@patch.object(auth, 'authenticate')
def test_login_missing_user(self, mock_auth):
    request = self.request_factory.post('', data={'email': u'test@abv.bg', 'password': u'PA$$WORD'})
    self.assertIsInstance(login(request), HttpResponse) #this test PASSES

    user = User.objects.create_user('test_user', 'test@testmail.com', 'test_password')

    mock_auth.return_value = True
    login(request)
    self.assertTrue(mock_auth.called)
```

The last assertion fails with AssertionError: False is not true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're patching the wrong thing: all you've done is change what `authenticate` refers to within your test, not in the view. You should patch `your_view.auth.authenticate`.

See the Mock docs on [Where to patch](http://mock.readthedocs.org/en/latest/patch.html#where-to-patch).

Comment: Link is 404, please update